# Error in Bugzilla Reporting extension Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 127 bytes

Tags: mediawiki, bugzilla

I can't understand why Bugzilla reporting is doing this I followed the explanation to the letter does anyone know what could be the cause of the problem. Would really appreciate this as I am very depressed that this happened. I also noticed that preview seems to be working fine the error is only given when save page is called.

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 127 bytes in
C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\objectcache\SqlBagOStuff.php on line
430 Call Stack
Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  257936  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0461  7296312 MediaWiki->run( )   ..\index.php:58
3   0.0461  7296656 MediaWiki->main( )  ..\Wiki.php:503
4   0.0504  8106552 MediaWiki->performRequest( )    ..\Wiki.php:593
5   0.0628  10005064    MediaWiki->performAction( ) ..\Wiki.php:278
6   0.0629  10005656    ViewAction->show( ) ..\Wiki.php:484
7   0.0629  10005984    Article->view( )    ..\ViewAction.php:40
8   0.1053  13999432    ParserCache->get( ) ..\Article.php:514
9   0.1053  13999992    ParserCache->getKey( )  ..\ParserCache.php:161
10  0.1054  14000456    SqlBagOStuff->get( )    ..\ParserCache.php:117
11  0.1059  14001320    SqlBagOStuff->unserialize(
)   ..\SqlBagOStuff.php:152 12  0.1059  14001776    unserialize (
)   ..\SqlBagOStuff.php:430

( ! ) Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 127 bytes in
C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\objectcache\SqlBagOStuff.php on line
430
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "bugzilla reporting". What do you mean by "Bugzilla Reporting extension", perhaps the [Bugzilla Reports](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Bugzilla_Reports) extension? How do you know that's the culprit?

Comment: Question is fairly clear, and so is the answer given by Enzero later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer install the latest version

http://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.22/mediawiki-1.22.5.tar.gz